# Java (javaws.exe) TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]

Tags: java, ssl

All I want is just get the Video Redirection for my Server to work...

The old onboard-management only provide TLS1.0. This server has a properly installed certificate, where corresponding CA is also installed on my computer.

I have changed `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\security\java.security`.

I tried everything, also to just delete TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 from the List. But that didn`t help. Even when the list is completely empty, I get the same error.

Changes made:

```
#jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, \
#    RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, \
#    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=
```

```
#jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \
#      DSA keySize < 1024, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=
```

```
#jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
#    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, RSA keySize < 2048, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
#    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=
```

The Server uses:
`The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.0, RSA, and AES_128_CBC with HMAC-SHA1.`

I have `jre1.8.0_291` and `jdk-15.0.1` installed. Both config files are identical in this regard (even thought the path is different: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\conf\security\java.security`.
I still get the above error.

When I issue `java --version` in cmd.exe I get this output:

```
java 15.0.1 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I also entered the URL of the Website, from where I download the .jnlp file, into the "Configure Java" Application whitelist.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try with this in the java.security file jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2

Comment: Try passing `java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` or just the version you need

Comment: I think TLS 1.0 was broken. As in there are real working exploits against the specification, so they removed it.

Comment: @SaleemKhair I cannot use java binary to open this file. I have to use `javaws avr.jnlp` to launch this applet. Your above option doesn't work with javaws.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch They did not remove TLS1.0; it is just disabled default now. See: https://www.java.com/de/download/help/release_changes.html#:~:text=TLS%201.0%20und%201.1%20wurden,das%20Java%20Control%20Panel%20verf%C3%BCgbar.

Comment: @jank04 That's a German link and to Java 8. OP is **also** using Java 15. And that is after the *modularity* rewrite of Java 11. So I suspect TLS1.0 is actually gone now.

Comment: Maybe relevant: The Java Control Panel Advanced Security Settings, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/java-control-panel.htm#JSDPG799

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Only Java JRE 8 has the javaws binary, therefore jdk 15 is not involved here.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch+ TLS1.0 has a known-IV _flaw_ that was briefly exploited by BEAST, but that was quickly (back in 2012) mitigated by fragmenting data and has never been reported in the wild. However since it is permanently in the vulnerabilty databases as 'severe', many checklisters such as PCI reflexively prohibit it. In contrast SSL3 is _really_ broken by POODLE. All modular versions of Java still implement 1.0, although 16 (not 15), 11.0.11, and 8u291 _disable_ it, and also 1.1, by default, which has been covered by numerous Qs already.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately I found the advanced tab in the "configure java" control panel. I can tick a checkbox there to use TLS1.0.

(Just as @JohannesB also commented).

I'll now change back to `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, \ RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, \ include jdk.disabled.namedCurves` and so on; therefore I can only accept my cipher suite and disallow any other older suites, which makes it a bit less insecure.

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue for a couple days and your answer gave me the clue I needed. The real fix was to find the Java options under Control Panel and under tab Advanced enable the algorithms I needed. Thanks for this! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can still modify `jre\lib\security\java.security` to not blacklist TLS 1.0 (at least on OpenJDK 1.8):

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=None
```

I've built a portable JAVAWS launcher for JNLP files that come from IPMI / IMM / ILO / IRMC / IDRAC / KVM servers that should work on a fair high number of old servers. Security settings in my portable launcher are already preset to support **prehistoric devices**.

You can find the project at https://github.com/netinvent/ipmi-starter